# Error when enabling Tiles with Struts2 Tiles plugin

Tags: maven, struts2, tiles, struts2-tiles-plugin

I get this error when I try to deploy Struts2 application with Tiles on Tomcat:

```
Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
```

Here is pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Nebula</groupId>
<artifactId>Nebula</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Nebula</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

And web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
     <display-name>Nebula</display-name>
     <context-param>
         <param-name>org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactory.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
     </context-param>
     <listener>
         <listener-class>
             org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
         </listener-class>
     </listener>
     <filter>
         <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
         <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
     </filter>
     <filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

This happened after I switched to Maven - before, when managing all JARs myself this wans't a problem.

I can see that the class `org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener` does exists.

Comment: Firstly, since you're using Maven, don't manage the dependencies it already manages for you--simply depend on `struts2-tiles-plugin` and it will manage the Tiles dependencies. That's the point of Maven. Secondly, if you put an SSCCE on Github or elsewhere someone can take a look; it could be your configuration, the rest of your POM, your deployment, etc.

Comment: I have updated the pom.xml and added web.xml to my question. If I add the JARs myself to the library and build path, then for some reason it works fine.

Comment: Works fine for me; cut-and-paste your pom and web.xml, so I suspect deployment or packaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new project from scratch and... it worked. Don't know what was the issue with the previous one.